# Let $p,q$ be real polynomials. Let $F: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable, then $p=q$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $p,q$ be real polynomials. Let $F: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable, defined by:

$$ F =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill q    \hfill & \text{X $\geq$ a} \\
      \hfill p \hfill & \text{X < a} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Then $F$ differentiable $\implies$ $F=p=q$.

I've been thinking about this for a while and think this is true, how could I prove/disprove it?

Comment: it's not true. Let $a=0$, $p(x)=x$, $q(x)=x^2+x$. Then $F$ is differentiable. It is true if you require $F$ to be infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Thanks, how can that be proved?

Comment: I'm certainly not answer that in comments. Way too long for the margin.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Taylor theorem?

Comment: It's better to ask a new question than to edit a new one into this post, given that you've already received an answer.

Comment: Noted. I will do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take $p(x)=0$ and $q(x)=x^2$, with $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, consider a polynomial $p(x)$, and let $q(x)$ be its tangent line at $x = a$, so that $q(x) = p'(a)(x - a) + p(a)$. Then the function $F$ you defined is continuous.